# Autocomplete doesn't work when the CellContext is set to be Notebook (Mathematica 13.3)

Tags: contexts, autocomplete, version-13.3

I am using mathematica 13.3. When the CellContext option is "Global" the autocomplete works fine. I would like to have individual variable in each notebook, so I use the following command:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> Notebook]
```

but now I find the autocomplete doesn't work. When I use `Context[]` to find the current context, and mannually type the context and continue to type the variable, the autocomplete works again.
Is this a bug?

Comment: Please don't add bugs tag before it's confirmed by WRI or the community.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I find the solution. In Preferences -> Interface Settings -> Input Assistance Settings, disable "Use fuzzy matching for autocompletions", autocomplete works again.