# Autocomplete for package in notebook with context "Unique To This Notebook"

Tags: packages, contexts

I have the setting that my notebooks their context is unique for each notebook to avoid accidental lingering definitions. I really need this because I'm often distracted and e.g. overwrite files when exporting results because `fileName` was already defined somewhere else or so.

When I load one of my own packages, the autocomplete doesn't work, as is stated in the documentation. This is quite annoying for testing.

Is there any way to still make autocomplete work?

---

Version: Mathematica 12.0 for mac

Comment: Does it work for you: [287846](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/287846/5478)?

Comment: I don't have the "Input assistance" option in my Preferences>Interface on Mathematica 12 :/